# How to get hibernate-entitymanager to work with JTA out of JBoss?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jndi, jta

I am building a tool for out-of-container EJB testing. I have managed to run Hibernate's EntityManager in it successfully. Now I want to integrate it with JTA to enable strict control of transactions.

The problem I am faced with is the following: Hibernate seems to require JNDI to work correctly with JBossTS (JBoss's JTA implementation). But I can't figure out a way how I can register `UserTransaction`s in JNDI.

What am I missing here? How can I configure JBossTS to work with Hibernate out of JBoss? Is there a tutorial on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try using another JTA implementation for use outside the EJB container? Spring has a pretty easy to use and good one.